# CSS Fix For Menu Mouse Over

Tags: css, menu, submenu

[On this page](http://glamourunderground.com), there's a menu with an automatically generated submenu under 'life'. There are some problems with the submenu (it flickers and changes size - you'll see if you scroll over it). Somehow I need to override the css that it's currently reading and make it uniform.

Any suggestions?

Thanks - Tara

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting at line 744 of `/wp-content/themes/primus/primus/style.css`, you have this CSS:

```
#catmenu  li li a:hover, #catmenu  li li a:active {
    background:#fff ;
    width: 150px;
    float: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
    color:#ff9999;

    }
```

Change the `padding` to match what it is before `hover`:

```
padding: 7px 10px
```

Answer (score 1):

It because you have set:

```
padding: 7px 10px 7px 10px;
```

on the a:link. And then you set padding to 0, on a:hover.

Try set the same padding values for both behaviors.

Comment: more quick: a:link,a:visited,a:active {padding:7px 10px;}

Comment: a:hover,active {padding:7px 10px;color:#ff0}

Comment: The idea is correct, but there are a lot of other `a` elements on the page. Adding the CSS in your comments would mess up many of the other links.

Comment: Yeah, it was a quick-n-dirt explanation. I will never read a whole css file for such a simple question like this.

Comment: Thanks @simone. It kinda worked. But now the submenu sometimes disappears once you try to scroll over it...?

Comment: @thirtydot That's ok, I just put it in like this #catmenu a:link,a:visited,a:active {padding:7px 10px;} - still not working 100% though

Comment: @Tara: I'll give @Simone a chance to fix it, but the problem is that `#catmenu a:link,a:visited,a:active {padding:7px 10px;}` is also applying to your "Life" link. I know that my answer worked when I posted it, because I tried it at the time.